# Using \bibliography when no style file exists

Tags: bibliographies

I have a question regarding the use of the \bibliography{} command.

For journal articles, I am accustomed to be supplied a myStyle.bst file (with bibtex entries in the file myBibliography.bib) such that before the end of the document I can run the commands:

```
\bibliography{myBibliography}
\bibliographystyle{myStyle}
```

to generate the bibliography in the manuscript.

However, for a publication I am currently working on, no myStyle.bst file was provided. In the sample template they provided, the bibliography is generated using the commands:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
    \bibitem{first} Foo. Author, Bar. Author.: TitleOfPaper. JournalName 1(4) (1900) 1-8
\end{thebibliography}
```

I don't want to manually parse through each bibtex entry and generate a \bibitem{} for each entry. I would rather generate my own style file or resolve the issue with some other solution. Note that the .cls file provided for the document formatting has no bibliography formatting. Thus, I would think the formatting is based on default values of the use of thebibliography environment and the formatting: "Foo. Author, Bar. Author.: TitleOfPaper. JournalName 1(4) (1900) 1-8".

How would I go about generating my own style file that accomplishes this?

Thank you!

Comment: There are several built-in styles, such as `unsrt`, `plain`, `alpha`, and `abbrv`.  Perhaps one already suits.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I have tried those default styles as well as those listed here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles, but they do not produce the desired result.

The most straightforward solution conceptually for me would then  be the hacking of a particular style, say for example plain.bst (http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/bibtex/plain.bst). Looking through the file, it is a little daunting. Do you by chance could direct me to a particular line which outputs the entry in a defined manner? Is it the ENTRY item at the very beginning?

Comment: To program in the stack-based bibtex language is to learn a whole new language.  Easiest, as you suggest, is to modify an existing `bst` file.  Resources for understanding how it works are "BibTeXing" by Oren Patashnik (1988) (http://bibtexml.sourceforge.net/btxdoc.pdf) and "Tame the Beast: The B to X of BibTeX" by Nicolas Markey (2009) (http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)

Comment: To get to your specific question, a line like `FUNCTION {article}` in the `bst` file identifies the routine that defines how entities identified as `article` will be formatted.  In turn, it calls on subroutines like `FUNCTION {format.authors}` in order to handle certain subfunctions of the bibliographic entry.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The two links in your first response were exactly what I was looking for in order to understand "Bibtexing". I was just trying to understand the language by guess and check by modifying the .bst file and seeing the effects in the publishing bibliography.

Comment: I've never been good with RPN-type syntax of stack-based languages, but after a while, one begins to get the hang of it.